# Allow multiple users to remote control a computer simultaneously over the network

Tags: keyboard, mouse, network-shares, multiple-users

Consider a network of 3 computers, A, B, and C.
I'm sitting at A, someone else is sitting at B, and we both would like to do things on C at the same time. That means I have a mouse cursor on C, the other person has another mouse cursor on C, and we are both doing different things at the same time. Same goes for the keyboard. Note that this requires A and B to log on the same session on C.

Is this possible? How? I have looked around but nothing seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Do they want to be in the same session on C (i.e. looking at the same desktop, seeing each other's actions, etc.) or each in their own session?  Which OSs are involved? What have you considered already, and why didn't they fit the bill?

Comment: I think @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's question is very relevant and not addressed by the answers below

Comment: Its not possible because if you two drag a document in opposite direction it might tear it and would be a lot of inconvenience :p

Answer (score 5):

You would need to install Windows Server on computer C.  Windows Server will allow two users to use Remote Desktop on their computers (A and B) and have individual desktop sessions on computer C.

Traditional/end-user remoting software like VNC, TeamViewer, PCAnywhere, do not allow for multiple users, as they *capture* the desktop session.

Comment: I *love* when people downvote the correct answer and dont leave a comment as to why they think its wrong.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about them both using the same session on C at once?  PS: I didn't down-vote your answer tho, as it's a plausible answer, but I think we need more info from the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry,  I wasn't clear that I would like to log on the same session... Is this possible? (+1 still)

Comment: No. It is not possible.